# As a subcontractor, how long should it take to get paid?

Tags: late-payment, subcontracting

It normally takes 6-8 weeks for the consulting firm I work for to pay me after I bill them for a month of my labor (I am a software developer). I currently have 3 outstanding invoices, and the oldest one was sent 9 weeks ago as of this writing. The contract states that they pay me within 5 days of receiving payment from the client.

To have a check sent to me, I usually have to talk to someone on the phone.

I am not sure if I am being treated poorly, or if this is typical of subcontracting arrangements. Is it "normal" for payments to take this long? The client is a pretty large company, so I understand that the gears turn a little slow, but 9 weeks?

Comment: I'm sorry but that sounds very bad. If this was me. I would be at their office and wouldn't leave until I got a cheque in my hand. After that. They have to pay in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply: if they are not adhering to the terms of the contract they agreed to, they are in breech of the agreement.

Yes, you are being treated poorly.

30 days is standard. But if they already agreed to 5 days, then the *most* you should be waiting is 10-15 days due to mail service, if they mail a check rather than paying electronically.